# Libreoffice Calc How to use either IF or Conditional Formatting for this problem

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have 8 forex pairs.
Each currency can be Strong, Weak, or Neutral.
-- this is manually entered
Based on those entries, the forex pair will show either Strong, Weak, or Neutral.

Forex comes in pairs.
The main pairs are:
AUD/USD
EUR/USD
EUR/JPY
GBP/JPY
GBP/USD
NZD/USD
USD/CAD
USD/CHF
USD/JPY

If the first currency (known as the base) is weak, and the second currency (known as the quote) is strong, then that pair will tend to be Weak.
If the base is strong, and the quote is weak, then the pair will tend to be Strong.

Weak = WS
Strong = SW

If either is neutral, then that would be treated as moderate weak or strong depending which currency is neutral.

Any ideas? I've got square eyes and it doesn't seem to matter if I try If statements or Conditional Formatting, I can't get even one to work properly. Which is all I really need to hack my way through the rest of them.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In general, your problem is understandable and completely solvable. The simplest solution would be to create a 3x3 matrix of all possible states and use it to calculate the state of a particular pair. However, the exact implementation of this approach is highly dependent on your data representation. Is the pair written in one cell or in two adjacent cells separately? Where and how stored status of currencies? If you supplement your problem description with samples of your data, you will get high-quality recommendations for solving the problem much faster.

Comment: Hey @JohnSUN. Thanks for the feedback.
Seems I was on the right track for the matrix.

I am not sure on a good way to represent that data so as not to make it more difficult than it has to be.

This is my thinking.

State (Up/Down/Neutral)

Manual Entries 
DXY  State
AUD State
GBP  State

Function
AUDUSD State
GBPAUD State

Now to figure out how to make that function work - which is my dilemma.